# Convert Dictionary of Dictionaries with list values to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been provided a very large dictionary with the following format that I am unsure how to convert to a dataframe that I can use to perform basic functions on.

```
{
    'hash': {
        'ids': [List of Unique IDs of records this hash has been seen in],
        'weights': [List of weights],
        'values': [List of values],
        'measure_dates': [List of dates]
    }
}
```

The number of items in `ids`, `weights`, `values` and `measure_dates` is the same within a `hash`. Different `hash`es can have a different number of items though. It depends on how often a measurement is taken.

Real(ish) data for an example of three records:

```
{
    'IRR-99876-UTY': {
        'ids': [9912234, 9912237, 45555889],
        'weights': [0.09, 0.09, 0.113],
        'values': [2.31220, 2.31219, 2.73944],
        'measure_dates': ['2021-10-14', '2021-10-15', '2022-12-17']
    },
    'IRR-10881-CKZ': {
        'ids': [45557231],
        'weights': [0.31],
        'values': [5.221001],
        'measure_dates': ['2022-12-31']
    },
    'IRR-881-CKZ': {
        'ids': [24661, 24662, 29431],
        'weights': [0.05, 0.07, 0.105],
        'values': [3.254, 4.500001, 7.3221],
        'measure_dates': ['2018-05-05', '2018-05-06', '2018-07-01']
    }
}
```

The value in an index corresponds to the same measurement being taken. For example in `IRR-881-CKZ`, there are 3 measurements.

- Measurement 1 taken on 2018-05-05, with id `24661`, weight `0.05`, and value `3.254`
- Measurement 2 taken on 2018-05-06, with id `24662`, weight `0.07` and value `4.500001`
- Measurement 3 taken on 2018-07-01, with id `29431`, weight `0.105` and value `7.3221`

No other combination of indexes is valid for this hash.

Information that I'm going to be attempting to get data on:

- Which hash(es) are measured the most often. This can be determined by which have the largest number of items in the `ids` list. In this example, the first and third record have three items so would be the top results. I'd love to be able to use something like `nlargest()` or `sort_values().head()` to get this, instead of parsing each record and counting the number of items.
- Which hashes have an average value between two values. If I had a set number of columns, I think I'd be able to do something like `df['average'] = df[['value1', 'value2']].mean(axis=1)`, but with a variable number of values I'm not sure how to do this.

How can I convert this dictionary of dictionaries of lists to a usable dataframe?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict).T` to create a usable df.

Comment: @SomeDude What does the `.T` do here that Lasse's answer below doesn't?

Comment: .T is transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert each entry of this dictionary into its own DataFrame and concatenate those to effectively work with this data:

### Creating a Usable DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'IRR-99876-UTY': {
        'ids': [9912234, 9912237, 45555889],
        'weights': [0.09, 0.09, 0.113],
        'values': [2.31220, 2.31219, 2.73944],
        'measure_dates': ['2021-10-14', '2021-10-15', '2022-12-17']
    },
    'IRR-10881-CKZ': {
        'ids': [45557231],
        'weights': [0.31],
        'values': [5.221001],
        'measure_dates': ['2022-12-31']
    },
    'IRR-881-CKZ': {
        'ids': [24661, 24662, 29431],
        'weights': [0.05, 0.07, 0.105],
        'values': [3.254, 4.500001, 7.3221],
        'measure_dates': ['2018-05-05', '2018-05-06', '2018-07-01']
    }
}

df = pd.concat(
    {k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in data.items()}, 
    names=['hash', 'obs']
)

print(df)
                        ids  weights    values measure_dates
hash          obs                                           
IRR-99876-UTY 0     9912234    0.090  2.312200    2021-10-14
              1     9912237    0.090  2.312190    2021-10-15
              2    45555889    0.113  2.739440    2022-12-17
IRR-10881-CKZ 0    45557231    0.310  5.221001    2022-12-31
IRR-881-CKZ   0       24661    0.050  3.254000    2018-05-05
              1       24662    0.070  4.500001    2018-05-06
              2       29431    0.105  7.322100    2018-07-01
```

Now that our data is cleaned up we can solve your questions.

### Solving Your Questions

1. Which hash(es) are measured the most often

- This is simply a [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) operation. However since the data we're interested in is currently in the index we'll need to grab it out using [`Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) first.

2. Which hashes have an average value between two values.

- This is a groupby operation where we calculate the average from the "values" column per unique "hash". From there we can use the [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) method to check whether a those averages exist between two arbitrary values.

```py
# Which hash(es) are measured the most often.
df.index.get_level_values('hash').value_counts()

# IRR-99876-UTY    3
# IRR-881-CKZ      3
# IRR-10881-CKZ    1
# Name: hash, dtype: int64

# ---
# Which hashes have an average value between two values.
## Here you can see that I'm testing whether the average is between 0 and 4
print(df.groupby('hash')['values'].mean().between(0, 4))

# IRR-10881-CKZ    False
# IRR-881-CKZ      False
# IRR-99876-UTY     True
# Name: values, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.from_dict()` in pandas to convert it to a dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

# dictionary of dictionaries with list values
data = {
    'IRR-99876-UTY': {
        'ids': [9912234, 9912237, 45555889],
        'weights': [0.09, 0.09, 0.113],
        'values': [2.31220, 2.31219, 2.73944],
        'measure_dates': ['2021-10-14', '2021-10-15', '2022-12-17']
    },
    'IRR-10881-CKZ': {
        'ids': [45557231],
        'weights': [0.31],
        'values': [5.221001],
        'measure_dates': ['2022-12-31']
    },
    'IRR-881-CKZ': {
        'ids': [24661, 24662, 29431],
        'weights': [0.05, 0.07, 0.105],
        'values': [3.254, 4.500001, 7.3221],
        'measure_dates': ['2018-05-05', '2018-05-06', '2018-07-01']
    }
}

# convert to data frame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Comment: Using this method puts each of the lists into a column. How can I find which hashes have an average value between X and Y with these lists? Can I just run `.mean()` over the list?

Comment: Yea, you can just do the following `df['values'].mean()` or you can use `apply` `df['average'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: sum(x)/len(x))`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get either of those to work with the lists. `.mean()` throws a TypeError, "complex() first argument must be a string or number, not 'list'". The `.apply()` throws a TypeError, "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'. Ideas?